# Modifying Stylesheets based upon ComboBox selection in QTCreator

Tags: c++, css, combobox

Forgive the mechanical engineer here but I am new to QTCreator and C++.

I am currently working on a GUI using QTCreator.  The system is designed to permit a user to modify a large number of system variables for a robotic device.  Thus I have roughly 1100 ComboBoxes spread over a number of StackedWidgets.

I have successfully implemented a few arrays to populate these boxes, and I can read the data back so the system is rather functional.

Here is the problem:  Each Page gets messy to the user due to the layout.  I would like to control the stylesheet of the combobox based upon the user selection.  i.e. if selected on the box turns green.  if Off - turns Red etc.

I can do this with a push button by running through the array, but the only way I can find to make it happen as the user makes changes is to activate the slot for each box upon index changed.

How oh how can I get the machine to loop looking for a change in any of about 80 boxes per page?

If you need my skill level, it did take a few days for me to figure out how to establish an array to populate the boxes, so I guess 1 level before NOOB. :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't compile this code so there are probably some errors, but this should give a good idea.

```
// This code goes in the place where you are adding the QComboBoxes
QComboBox* box = new QComboBox()
connect(box, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int index)), this, SLOT(UpdateColor(int idx));   

// Add this function to the class where you are adding the QComboBoxes
void UpdateColor(int idx)
{
    if(idx == 0) // OFF
    {
        QObject::sender()->setStyleSheet("QComboBox { selection-background-color: red; }");
    }
    else if(idx == 1) //ON
    {
        QObject::sender()->setStyleSheet("QComboBox { selection-background-color: green; }");
    } 
}
```

`QObject::sender()` returns a pointer to the object that initiated the signal, in this case the `QComboBox` whose selection just changed.  There should be no need to loop through the boxes because this function gives you the box that just changed.

Comment: Thanks Rick.   I will certainly give that a try.  I do appreciate your help.